# npx create-next-app <app_name> --template redux doesn't create redux template

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I want to create a redux template while creating the next js app but when I try to setup a redux template with next js like this

```
npx create-next-app <app_name> --template redux
```

does not create a redux template. Just create next app like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question might better be asked as an issue in CRA's [Github repo](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues).

Comment: whitch version of npm you are using?

Comment: I am using the latest version of node and which is 16.17.1